# Поделиться изображением (sharing) через intent

Tags: java, android

Нужно через intent сделать возможность поделиться изображением из ресурсов. Текст отображается нормально, а вот само изображение при подготовке к публикации (например в ВК), при загрузке пишет "ошибка". Uri однозначно правильный. Помогите плиз, в чем может быть проблема.
Вот пример кода.

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.shppcs.igo/" + R.drawable.ic_gomer_run_jpeg);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Я бросаю тебе вызов");
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Бросить вызов"));
```

Comment: попробуй сделать так -( "android.resource://com.shppcs.igo/drawable/" + R.drawable.ic_gomer_run_jpeg)

Comment: К сожалению... Никакой разницы.